# How to overwrite a json object?

Tags: javascript

I have json object with a key named favorite, it has a value of true, when the button is pressed I want to overwrite the value of the favorite key to false and vica versa.

This is what`s inside the json object:

```
allPlaces: "[{"title":"Test1 ","description":"Test 2","category":"restaurant","favourite":false}]"
```

```
function favourite(element) {

    var allPlaces = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPlaces"));
    var placeIndex = element.getAttribute("data");

    places = {allPlaces}
    
    if (allPlaces["favourite"] == true) {

        places.favourite[placeIndex] = false;

        element.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star-outline');

    } else {
        console.log("working");
        places.favourite[placeIndex] = true;

        element.style.color = '#FFE234';
        element.querySelector('ion-icon').setAttribute('name', 'star');
    }
    localStorage.setItem("allPlaces", JSON.stringify(places));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allPlaces` is an array (in this case it has 1 item) so therefore in order to change the property of an object inside it you have to give it an index like so `allPlaces[0].favorite = true`

I added some code as a reference

```js
const allPlaces = '[{"title":"Test1 ","description":"Test 2","category":"restaurant","favourite":false}]';
const places = JSON.parse(allPlaces);
places[0].favorite = true;
console.log(places[0]);
```